# Un équivalent de « the more you stir it the worse it stinks » ?

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

En anglais on a l'adage ou proverbe « the more you stir it the worse it stinks » pour « the more closely an unsavory business is examined, the more unpleasant it is » [plus on examine de près une affaire désagréable, plus elle est désagréable (DeepL)]. [Historiquement](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/merde) on semble déjà avoir eu quelque chose de similaire mais aujourd'hui « [remuer la merde](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/remuer_la_merde) » signifierait *envenimer* ou *faire resurgir* une affaire embarrassante (Wiktionnaire).

[image]

<sup>[*Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LMGPCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA300&ots=lHYebkFpa4&dq=%22the%20more%20you%20stir%20it,%20the%20worse%20it%20stinks%22%20meaning&pg=PA300&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20more%20you%20stir%20it%2C%20the%20worse%20it%20stinks%22%20meaning&f=false), Oxford University Press, 2015</sup>

---

A-t-on un proverbe/adage de même sens que celui en anglais aujourd'hui ?

Comment: Ça rappelle ce bon mot d'un agriculteur de Reims : « Plus ça pu plus c'est bon ! ».  https://www.champagnefm.com/news/plus-ca-pue-plus-c-est-bon-44635

Answer (score 4):

La même expression existe en français, mais contrairement à l'anglais, on n'a pas pris l'habitude d'omettre le mot grossier.

> Plus on remue la merde, plus elle pue.
> Quand on remue la merde, ça pue.

(Les deux variantes existent, je ne sais pas si c'est une différence régionale.)

C'est de cette expression que vient le sens figuré de « remuer la merde » (de même que « *stirring shit* » en anglais).

Answer (score 1):

Il y a un proverbe Danois que l'on peut très bien utiliser en français, en le référant à son origine ou non.

- ([DICOCITATIONS](https://www.dicocitations.com/citations/citation-46214.php))  Plus on remue la boue, plus elle empeste.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas qu'il existe une traduction de l'expression complète, mais une métaphore appropriée existe pour la première moitié: *Plus on creuse, plus [...]*. C'est probablement cela que j’utiliserais pour traduire cette expression.

Answer (score 0):

***Action and consequence; busybodies*** est donné à la fin de l'explication de ce proverbe en anglais selon cette citation Oxford.  Les proverbes sont catégorisés en gras à fin et dans la même catégorie se trouve tout simplement, **trop de cuisinières gâtent la sauce**.  Trop de mains sales ou salées rendent la sauce dégoûtante.

> Ce [proverbe](https://www.linternaute.fr/proverbe/287/trop-de-cuisiniers-gatent-la-sauce/) s'emploie quand trop de personnes se consacrent à un même
> objet

Plus qu'on s'en mêle, voilà.  *On* est des cuisinières.

*Remuer la merde* est une traduction très équivalente de *stir up shit* ou *stir the pot* en anglais.  Ce dernier est plus « poli » quant aux gros mots.  Pareil pour *mettre le pieds dans le plat*.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que _too many cooks spoil the broth_ signifie la même chose que _the more you stir it the worse it stinks_... ils partagent les mêmes mots-clés dans l'ouvrage d'Oxford parce que tous deux impliquent un conséquence à une action et un intérêt pour quelque chose d'extérieur à soi-même. Par exemple, un truc comme « l'homme indiscret meurt de misère » serait possiblement classé aussi de la sorte, mais ne signifie pas la même chose que l'expression dans ma question...

Comment: Non, les sens ne sont pas équivalents ; dans le proverbe anglais l'idée est tout simplement que faire de la recherche mets à découvert encore plus de faits malhonnêtes, alors que l'idée dans le proverbe français c'est que trop d'initiatives d'origine diverses sans une directive commune pour les accorder résultent en un effet négatif.